# Managing Window life cycle in Android

Tags: android

In an application, I create an overlay Window by using WindowManager. Can I manage life cycle of created Window like [Activity life cycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle). For exmple:

1. Is it necessary to release created Window after completing it's work?
2. How I can destroy Window?
3. Can I destroy Window by removing all views from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[WindowManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.html) inherited from [ViewManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewManager.html)

`WindowManager` which relate to the three important methods are:

[addView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewManager.html#addView(android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams))

Assign the passed LayoutParams to the passed View and add the view to the window

[updateViewLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewManager.html#updateViewLayout(android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams))

Used to update the view attached to the window

[removeView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewManager.html#removeView(android.view.View))

Used to remove the view that bind by `addView`

> You could manage window with respective to the component on which you
>   created the window. you can destroy the window using `removeView`
>   method from `ViewManager`. Say, If you have created the window in a
>   `Service` class you can addView from `onCreate` method of service
>   class and you should destroy the window by calling `removeView` method probably in `onDestroy`.

**Is it necessary to release created Window after completing it's work?**

Ans :- Always recommended to release the instances once you have done with it and It's the best practise as well.

[Link](http://www.phonesdevelopers.info/1762497/)